# php js working with event start date and end date

Tags: javascript, php, date

i am working on script that work with event, event start 12/02/2016 11:20 and end 01/04/2016 8:20
when i reaching the end date i need to trigger an action what i tried using js

```
if (t.getFullYear()===ey && t.getMonth()===em && t.getMonth()===ed) {
    //the event still happening check the time
}

if (t.getFullYear()<ey && t.getMonth()<em && t.getMonth()<ed) {
    //the event is still not ended
}

if (t.getFullYear()>ey && t.getMonth()>em && t.getMonth()>ed) {
    //the event is dead 
}
```

where ey stands for year 
and em for month 
and ed for day like so ey=2016,em=07,ed=05
i am thinking about this enddate-startdate=timestamp to trigger action how can i do this using php ?

Comment: I don't quite get your question... you want to know how to call the php from js? or how to translate the js to php?. As a side note, you need to be careful on controlling stuff in your server based on client dates, client dates will vary based on the client physical location (PST, EST, etc). If you are already handling this on your server or you are ok to having this time differences on your event call, then you're good.

Answer (score 0):

i think i was look at the problem from different angle , all it took 5s ajax request and server side php check 
if (today-enddate<0) 
fire action 
else 
wait